# In TS, why number[][number] === number?

Tags: typescript

[image]

```js
type Test = number[][number]; // Test will be inferred to 'number' as the above image show.
```

Why `number[]` is an index signature type with signature 'number'?

Comment: I think you are getting thrown off by the use of `number` in two contexts in the type. `string[][number]` is the equivalent to `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a way how you get union of types of values.

it is the same as: there is an array of numbers `number[]`, we say `[number]`, that means give us a union of types of values that belong to numeric key, because it's an array of numbers the result is `number`.

```
type TestObject = {
  test1: string;
  test2: number;
};

// union of all keys is string | number
type TestValueUnion = TestObject[keyof TestObject];

// 'test1' | 'test2'
type TestKeyUnion = keyof TestObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQPty.png)

number[]  mean a array

when you want to get the type of array, you can add [randomInput]

so number[][number] mean get the type of number[]

number[][xxx] is also equal number   try it